Help understanding elisp debugger error
I am writing a function to set a BLOCKER property on tasks under certain conditions. The logic is working fine, but I am getting an error I cannot make sense of.
When executing the function on a org fle, Elis enters the Debugger with the message:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (org-set-property "BLOCKER"  (concat "previous-sibling " blocker)))
    (let ((blocker nil) (prop nil) (tidy nil))
     
              (org-map-entries (lambda ()

                            (setq blocker (org-entry-get (point) "BLOCKER"))

                            (if blocker
                                (if (not (string-match "previous-sibling" blocker))
                                    (setq prop t))
                              (setq prop t))

                            (if (org-entry-get (point) "NOBLOCKING")
                                (setq prop nil))

                            (if prop
                                (progn (
                                        (org-set-property "BLOCKER" (concat "previous-sibling " blocker))
                                        (setq tidy t)))
                              (setq tidy nil))
                        )
                     "LEVEL=1 TODO=PHASE" nil))

I am 100% sure my code is convoluted, I am not comfortable declaring and modifying variables with elisp, and I only know (message x) when I want to check where I messed up.
But, I have tried the (org-set-property "BLOCKER"  (concat "previous-sibling " blocker))  bit in a lot of different ways, using the M-: eval line, trying outside and with org-map-entries in a code block. It always works fine.
All I could think of was that the blocker variable was causing the problem, but 'concatworks fine if I replace it withnil, and according to the doc, org-entry-getcan only return a string (possibly empty) or anilvalue. Also, I am not doing anything withblocker` in the code, only checking a few conditions to decide to set the property or not...
I must be missing something, but after a couple of hours going in circle I need the help of fresh eyes, or maybe learn a way to debug better.
Thanks in advance.

(progn ( (org-set-property -> (progn (org-set-property

Thanks a ton, I feel even more relieved than dumb right now ! Fresh eyes was the answer I guess.

Do you understand now why the debugger complained about "invalid-function"? If not, you should stop for a few minutes and try to understand it. That way, you will be better prepared for the next debugging session.

Yes I do, thank you. I actually already encountered this situation. I should have focused more on understanding the debug message instead of trying to go over all the usual suspects (of which the primary always is the parenthesis in my case!). I could blame it on fatigue and heat, but it is true that everything was in the error message.


When executing the function on a org fle, Elis enters the Debugger with the message: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (org-set-property "BLOCKER"  (concat "previous-sibling " blocker)))

Everything you needed was in this error message.

But, I have tried the (org-set-property "BLOCKER"  (concat "previous-sibling " blocker)) bit in a lot of different ways, using the M-: eval line, trying outside and with org-map-entries in a code block. It always works fine.

But it is clear that you misread it. You appear to have assumed that it is saying that org-set-property is not a valid function. But if that were the case, the error message would have read (invalid-function org-set-property instead.
Because the error included the whole expression (org-set-property "BLOCKER"  (concat "previous-sibling " blocker)), it means that it was evaluating your code and found this expression where it was expecting a function name. The whole expression (org-set-property …) is clearly not a function but is a function call. You can immediately deduce that you must have a double opening parenthesis somewhere in your code where one isn’t allowed.
You’ll get the same kind of error from this much simpler code:
((foo) 2 2)

If you really do want to call some function returned by some other function, you have to use funcall to do it. Consider this example:
(defun foo ()
  (if (eq 2 (calendar-day-of-week (calendar-current-date)))
      #'-
    #'+))

(funcall (foo) 2 2)


As a tangent, elisp still supports a "rarely used [and] now deprecated" special case for lambda forms.  It may stop working in a future release, but for now you can evaluate ((lambda (x) (format "[%d]" x)) 42) => "[42]" for example.  Don't do this; but in case you ever see an example in the wild, it's valid.

Tangential remark: some Lisps (e.g. Scheme) evaluate the operator argument in a form using the same rules as for the operand arguments - that's not the case for Emacs Lisp.

Yea, I wondered if I should include more details in the answer or not.
